How to query RDF data which uses "Singleton Property" approach, in GraphDB?
Singleton property is an RDF metadata representation approach.  I need  a sample SPARQL query in GraphDB. This is an example RDF data:
:man :hasSpouse#1 :woman .
:hasSpouse#1 :startDate "2020-02-11"^^xsd:date .

Based on the Singleton property documentation, we need to use "#" at the end of the predicate but I couldn't use it in SPARQL. GraphDB considers it as a comment. Any solution?

which documentation do you refer to? I don't see why there should be an # char at the end. The original approach was published in this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281896322_On_Reasoning_with_RDF_Statements_about_Statements_using_Singleton_Property_Triples/download?_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6Il9kaXJlY3QiLCJwYWdlIjoiX2RpcmVjdCJ9fQ - there is no such requirement mentioned. I also don't think this is a common way of reification nowadays. For anything else, in Turtle as well as SPARQL you can always use the full URI if you are unsure about short form representations.

This is the original paper I refered to: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4350149/

In the paper you refered  there is an example:
SELECT ?professor
WHERE {
?professor worksFor University2 .
?student ?sp ?professor .
?sp singletonPropertyOf hasAdvisor .
?sp since "2009" . }
Based on this example we dont need to put # in the code and that is great.

just a question: based on this example, do you think we should define two classes in the uplift code (R2RML) or one? I mean one for sp and one for hasAdvisor?


If you use singleton props, you should also have a link from every SP to a generic prop in this case hasSpouse. Otherwise how would you know which SP to query in SPARQL?
But I would recommend NOT to use SP's because they are expensive by "polluting" the "P" indexes of the database with too many entries, and complicating SPARQL queries. Use RDF-star instead:

:man hasSpouse :woman . 
<<:man hasSpouse :woman>> :startDate "2020-02-11"^^xsd:date 

See https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.6/rdf-sparql-star.html#how-the-different-approaches-compare and https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283865828_Reifying_RDF_What_works_well_with_wikidata

The local part of a prefixed name can’t contain #. This is the case for SPARQL and for Turtle.
Escaping
You can escape # with a backslash:
# Turtle
:man :hasSpouse\#1 :woman . 
:hasSpouse\#1 :startDate "2020-02-11"^^xsd:date .

# SPARQL
?person1 :hasSpouse\#1 ?person2 .

Custom prefix
Another option could be to use a custom prefix:
PREFIX hasSpouse: <https://example.com/hasSpouse#>

# Turtle
:man hasSpouse:1 :woman . 
hasSpouse:1 :startDate "2020-02-11"^^xsd:date .

# SPARQL
?person1 hasSpouse:1 ?person2 .


I used backslash but it didn't work.

@Sepid: Could you post an (anonymized) full IRI of a hasSpouse singleton property? I wonder if it’s maybe encoded differently.
